# memcpy_s C++ pointer

Tags: c++, vector, memcpy

I have a question using `memcpy_s`.

```
std::vector<char> MyBuf;   
MyBuf.resize(10);

char* p = &MyBuf[0];
```

Now I want to copy using `memcpy_s` to the data of the `vector` using the pointer `p`.

```
memcpy_s(XXXXX, 10, "BOBBO", 5);
```

What do I need to enter instead of `XXXXX`?

When using `&p[0]` instead of `XXXXX` I get a memory exception.

Comment: I think it's obvious to use `p`. Where's the catch?..

Comment: Why, just why use `memcpy_s()` when `memcpy()` is totally fine and does its job (and isn't "deprecated")?

Answer (score 5):

1. If using C++11, don't use `&MyBuf[0];`, use `MyBuf.data()` instead.
2. The pointer to use is `p`.
3. Copy one character more if you want the destination to be usable as a string, you're missing the terminator.

Comment: Although note `data()` is `c++11` only.

Comment: It's a recommended way to use `&MyBuf[0]` prior to `C++11`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9f6s1wf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead. It is faster and safer.

```
const char* str = "BOBBO";
std::copy(str, str + sizeof(str), MyBuf.begin());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `MyBuf.data()` as a destination pointer if you have C++11 standard library. Using `&MyBuf[0]` should work, but is unnecessarily ugly.